# Is there a low-effort online sprint planning tool I can use to manage small student-project teams?

Tags: web-apps, project-management

I'm teaching a college software engineering course, where the students are divided into small teams of 2-3 people. Throughout the semester the students work on their software projects, and I like to introduce them to **agile sprint management** tools. Would you recommend any online sprint management tools (both paid or free) to help with this?

**Note**: I've lightly looked into **Atlassian Jira Agile**, which seems to be overkill (and a higher learning curve for students). I've had students try **Trello**, which is too lightweight, because I can't view their progress without going to each person's page. If there is a way to easily upgrade or configure these products, that is an ok answer too!

Here are my criteria:

- Students can add tasks and subtasks
- Students can add points/hours to tasks as estimates
- Students can assign tasks to people
- Students can mark tasks as not-started, in-progress, completed
- Students can add labels tasks as different themes or topics
- Students can add sprints / delete sprints
- As a teacher, I can create projects and assign students to a project
- As a teacher, I can see student projects
- As a teacher, I can see agile-burndowns of student points vs accomplished over time
- As a teacher, I can see individual student

Comment: I just found www.scrumdo.com, which is like a trimmed-down version of Jira Agile with KanBan. The cost is quite high though.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been using [VersionOne](https://www.versionone.com/pricing-and-editions/) at my current (mid-sized) company for quite a while.  It addresses most, if not all, of your criteria and comes as a free or paid solution including...

- [The ability to prepare
  backlogs](https://www.versionone.com/product/agile-project-management-software/)
  by creating stories ('projects'), tasks, sub-tasks, and epics.
- Assigning and prioritizing tasks with points and hours as estimates.
- Scheduling and planning sprints.  This includes assigning story and
  task status.
- Conducting reviews and retrospectives after each "sprint".
- Managing and reporting progress on a member by member basis.  This includes burn downs.

VersionOne provides a free version.  I would encourage you to try it out, or, view one of their many [support videos](https://community.versionone.com/) that explain their features in depth.  We use the in-house version, but, a [hosted](https://www.versionone.com/product/integrations/deployment-options/) version is also available.

Comment: Could you please describe which features it does support, and which it doesn't support?